# Flutter Cloud Firebase set Custom ID (upload)

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore

I would like to upload a file to the cloud firestore database, but not with a randomly generated id, but one that I set. How do I do this, I ran my sample code below.
Thanks for your help

```
final db = Firestore.instance;

String name = "Test";
String id = "id1";

...

upload() async {
DocumentReference ref = await db.collection("ka").add({"name" : "$name"});
    setState(() {
      ref.??? "documentID";
    });
  }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can provide documentId of your choice like shown below.

```
db.collection("ka")
      .document("DocumentIdOfYourChoice")
      .setData({
        'name': '$name',
      });
```

Answer (score 0):

**Note:** *In the newer version of firestore function/method name have changed e.g. instead of document() use doc() and instead of setData() just use set()*

```
db.collection("ka")
      .doc("DocumentIdOfYourChoice")
      .set({
        'name': '$name',
        });
```